# Moving row data to certain tabs

Tags: office-scripts

[image: Worksheet]

I receive a daily Excel file that has around 15K rows and 22 columns. There are a few hundred different values in column A. I want to copy or move certain rows to predefined tabs. For example, everything with the value "Home" would be moved to Sheet2, "Work" would be moved to Sheet3 etc.

Any guides to for follow for this or ideas?

Comment: I would recommend starting by using the macro recorder. Once the code is recorded, you could either look into using it as it is or modifying it to your needs.

Comment: I am having trouble selecting what I need since the range is dynamic. I use Data / Filter to get my value.

sheet1.getRange("A1").copyFrom(selectedSheet.getRange("A1:AK20062"), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.values, false, false);

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt at a script that gets the result I think you want. Note the use of the 'getUsedRange()' method. It helps you access ranges of various sizes. There are probably several other ways to do this in typescript/javascript or by doing the filtering with Excel APIs.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  //get the used range, assuming there is one worksheet
  let worksheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
  let range = worksheet.getUsedRange();
  let rangeValues = range.getValues();
  
  // create an array to hold all the unique values in the first column skipping the header row
  let firstCol: string[] = [];
  rangeValues.forEach((curRow, index) => {
    if (index > 0) {
      firstCol.push(curRow[0].toString());
    }
  });
  let uniqueFirstCol = firstCol.filter((val, ind, arr) => arr.indexOf(val) === ind);

  // run thru all the unique values, filter as appropriate and add filtered values to new worksheets
  uniqueFirstCol.forEach(v => {
    let tempValues = rangeValues.filter((row, index) => row[0] === v);
    let newSheet = workbook.addWorksheet(v);
    let newRange = newSheet.getRangeByIndexes(1,0, tempValues.length, tempValues[0].length);
    newRange.setValues(tempValues);
    newSheet.getRangeByIndexes(0,0, 1, rangeValues[0].length).setValues([rangeValues[0]])
  });
}
```